# SQL Connection without log steal

Tags: c#

I'm making a game with a login system which connect to a database, but my source code is not crypted and I worried about if someone decompile my program, he can get the SQL logins and wanted to know how prevent from that?

Comment: Don't connect to SQL directly; use a second layer like a HTTP API or something. You don't want your clients connecting to your database (in this particular case).

Comment: How does it works? (Sorry I'm not very good in C#)

Comment: How about you try and do some research before asking when someone points you in the right direction? If you want to become good in C# (or programming in general; hell even in life in general) you'll have to learn to think and work yourself and only ask for help if you've tried something and can at least explain what you're asking for *specifically*. If you've done your homework it'll show and you'll be able to ask *concrete* questions; not *general* questions like "how does it works?"

Comment: SQL can either use a SQL credential or a Windows Credential.  Using Windows Credentials you don't need to specify the password it automatically uses the encrypted windows password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since .NET Framework 2.0, there is a possibility of encrypting application configuration sections. However, it needs a bit of implementation.

Please refer to the following article.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53tyfkaw(v=vs.110).aspx

Just another option... You can consider using "Integrated Security=SSPI" in your connection string. This will try to open connection to database with the user running your application main thread. However, this will require additional management on the SQL server side for permissions of the user but you won't be providing any usernames or passwords in your connection string.

And a note... Although i partially agree with Roblll with the comment on research, sometimes people need advice for the concept. If concept is not there and you are lost, you cannot share a line of code right? I think stackoverflow is a great platform to ask and learn from replies. So keep on asking... Do your homework and don't be shy! :)

Cheers